# Nested ui-views not working in Angular 1.2.0-rc.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been trying all day to get the AngularUI Router working with 1.2.0-rc.3, but to no avail. I'm pretty sure it's a bug, as a lot of things have been changed in rc3, but maybe someone has found a workaround for it.

This is what I'm trying to do:

**In my `app.config()`**

```
var login = {
    url        : '/login',
    name       : 'login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginCtrl'
};
var main = {
    url        : '/',
    name       : 'main',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller : 'MainCtrl'
};
var reportsOverview = {
    url        : '/reports',
    name       : 'main.reports',
    controller : 'ReportsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.reports.html'
};

$stateProvider.state(login);
$stateProvider.state(main);
$stateProvider.state(reportsOverview);
```

When I go to `/login`, my template gets displayed as expected. When I go to `/` or `/reports` however, I see nothing. I've got a `<div ui-view></div>` in both my `index.html` and `views/main.html` file, so that's not the issue.

Anyone out there experiencing the same issue, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard without being able to see the custom templates, but some things I noticed that you are going to `/reports`. Urls are additive, so, in your case because the main url is `/` and your reports url is `/reports` the actual url you would have to go to is `//reports` not `/reports`. Try making your reports url `reports` and then `/reports` should work.

I would try to use `ui-sref` directive to create links on your web page so that you can see what urls the routing is generating for each state and check that it is what you expect.

It would be really helpful if you could include a plunkr that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: That totally makes sense, wow. Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm!